# Loading div with only a portion of the paragraph text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a headline news feed for my home page by using the Jquery .load function.

I am loading the page news.html and I can target the first elements (the latest news stories).

```
$( "#headline" ).load( "news.html .media-left:first, .media-body:first", function() {

    $( "#headline" ).append("<a class='pull-right' href='news.html'>...Read more</a>");

});
```

but what I can't figure out is how to only pick up the div and the first two paragraphs within that div, so that I can create a read more button to take them to the main news.html, every time I try to reference a portion of the paragraphs, it only includes the paragraph and doesn't include the div media.body which has the styles attached to it.

```
<div class="media menu-center">
    <div class="media-left">
        <div class="donut-yellow">
        <h4>
            <span class="month">May</span>
            <span class="day">23rd</span>
        </h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media-body media-right ">
       <p class="media-heading"><strong>e </strong></p>
       <p>Welcome to the brand new ****!</p><p>To ensure that we continue to(...)</p>
       <p>Take a look around the new layout and make sure to keep an eye on this(...)</p>

       <span class="pull-right"><p class="bg-success"><strong>Paul</strong></p></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to retrieve the entire document, then grab the parts you want from that object. Is the HTML above what's being returned, or the entire file?

Comment: Is there any way you can create a different news.html which has the correct html already generated? It would have only the latest stories, the first two paragraphs of each and the correct read more links / styles. Would save the hassle of trimming it all using JS and increase performance.

Comment: Yeah that is an example of what is being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector seems to work:

```
$( "#headline" ).load( "news.html .media-body>p:nth-child(-n+2)", function() {

    $( "#headline" ).append("<a class='pull-right' href='news.html'>...Read more</a>");

});
```

I've tested it in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5y2xj2z/).

It returns:

> e
>
> Welcome to the brand new ****!

Comment: Ah that looks good but unfortunately if you have more than one lot of news item then it will import first 2 paragraph from every news item.

Comment: This is why .media-body:first is used, maybe I am tackling this in the wrong way? http://jsfiddle.net/e5y2xj2z/2/

Comment: You then should use its parent, to select that first one: `$(".media:first-of-type .media-body>p:nth-child(-n+2)")`, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e5y2xj2z/3/)